# Script SCP without certificates or expect

Tags: scp, hp-ux, ksh

I need to script SCP and I **need** to be able to do this by passing in the password in plain text. I am absolutely aware of the **horrible** design pattern that I am asking for. I **cannot use certificates** for this application. My challenge is that the box that I am working on cannot and willnot have expect or perl's Net::SFTP module. I have an HP-UX box with ksh and a basic perl install.

Using SSH keys is out because of a workplace requirement. I don't make the policy, but I do have to abide by it.

Comment: I'm not sure what are your requirements but you can do it by using some `socat` dark magic like so: `(sleep 3; echo PASS; sleep 5; echo "uname -a") | socat - EXEC:'ssh -l user hostname',pty,setsid,ctty`. In the name of all that is holy, please don't use this for a production environment :)

Comment: That's a good idea, and it works, although I'm going to take a wild guess that if he can't have expect, he also can't have socat.

Comment: fim, that is some pretty slick magic... but Some Guy is right, I have no socat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - you can't do this without external help from expect or similar to provide the password.

What is the objection to using SSH keys? If it's just a case of not wanting to use SSH keys without a pass phrase then you can always set up [ssh-agent](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent) to hold the keys for you.

Comment: workplace policy...

Comment: Then you're out of luck - start schmoozing the policy makers.

Answer (score 2):

By certificates, do you mean ssh keys? Because you can always generate an ssh key with a blank passphrase and use that to log in without being prompted.

Comment: Yes, by certificates I mean SSH keys. This is by far what I would prefer to do, but I cannot.

Comment: Do you mind if I ask why you can't use keys?

Comment: workplace policy...

Comment: Well, we've all worked at places with weird (or silly) policies, so I can kind of understand that, however... this might be one of those cases where it makes sense to question the policy. I'm guessing this is some kind of short-sighted security policy, which is going to have the end effect of making you come up with an even less secure solution just to satisfy the policy.

Comment: We use HP-UX and, for user accounts, cannot use ssh-keys, the box is configured that way. The reasoning is that keys can be passed around .. (as if passwords couldn't) and would thus allow "anonymous" access. I disagree, but as the OP, I have to abide. Some 'security auditor' is being blamed (more likely misquoted)